# How do I fix my netman (Huawei E3531) usb broadband internet in ubuntu 14.04.3 it connects but do not display web pages

Tags: mobile-broadband

It ask me my password and then it connects but do not display web pages ( the blue light is on) I can send ussd and get an answer back. Please help